# Create '+' a case symbol missing on account in CRM 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

'+'  sign to create a case on customer/account is missing in CRM 2016. Though the role has all the privileges to create , read, write and append , append to. See the screen shot below, missing + sign:

Tried removing and adding the security roles again, it didn't help. Also it does not  appear in admin role as well. Any Suggestions ? 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely because the relationship is not a navigable relationship. When you click the drop-down arrow you should see Cases (I'm assuming the system does not have more than one relationship between Account and Cases.) If you do not have the relationship showing here you will not get a **+** sign to add a new record

[image: Relationships configured on the form]

To add the relationship to the form edit the form and add the relationship to the left-hand navigation configuration.

[image: Edit the form to add the relationship]

Comment: Hi, I have relationship set up between cases and accounts and I also see cases in the navigation pane as you have it in screen shot above.

Comment: this missing navigation will hide the 'Associated View' button. still 'Add New' button should be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Provided, the security role having Create privilege for Incident entity, this button should appear.

The problem could be because of 2 reasons.

1. Either someone customized the ribbon to hide the 'Add New' button from subgrid menu

or

2. Subgrid should be inside a Quick view form. In this case - Lock symbol will appear before text "Recent Cases" which is not true in your case

Moreover I personally tested by removing the left navigation in form, 'Add New' button is still visible, only 'Associated View' is removed.